# Clone function on apex missing to copy fields

Tags: apex, clone

I've done a code to auto-renew contracts when they arrive to their renewal date. 
My idea is to create an exact clone of the old contract, change it's start date for the renewal date of the old contract and put it as draft. To acomplish this I've used this:

```
...
    for(Contract contractToRenew: (List<Contract>) scope) { 
                    Contract contractToInsert = contractToRenew.clone(false,true,false,false); // (preserveId, isDeepClone, preserveReadonlyTimestamps, preserveAutonumber)
                    contractToInsert.StartDate = contractToRenew.Next_Renewal_Date__c;
                    contractToInsert.Renewed_Contract__c = contractToRenew.Id;
                    contractToInsert.Status = 'Draft';
                    contractsToInsert.add(contractToInsert);
                    contractToRenew.Status = 'Finished';
                    EmailsToSend.add(generateEmail(ContractToRenew));
                }
...
```

But still after I insert the new created contract some of the fields that were not null on the old contract are empty on this recently cloned one. And ofc I don't have any trigger or workflow that clears those fields.

As far as I've look into the clone documentation I think i'm using the clone parameters that meet my needs.

Am I using deep clone wrong? Or what else should I take a look into?

Comment: clone copy only queried field

Comment: Damn that was just pretty damn simple, I was overthinking something that easy. Post it as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I don't want to steal the thunder from @kurunve (so I'm resisting the urge to make my own answer here). Instead, I'll simply note that querying fields is not the only way to have `SObject.clone()` clone the data. The real requirement is that the fields be populated, on the object instance you want to clone, _in memory_ (as opposed to in the database). Querying is one way of getting field data 'in memory'. The other ways to do that are to set a value for the field via Apex, bind the field in a Visualforce page (and set the value), or pull the record from a trigger context variable.

Comment: In opposition to the first comment which was info I already knew but forgot I knew. This is something new and pretty interesting to know. 
I would propose to wait a couple of days to see if kurunve answers and otherwise I would accept our answer with all this information added , which I think is pretty useful as well.
Thanks.